# Como utilizar o RedirectMatch para redirecionar à outra página?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, redirect

Tenho uma aplicação feita em wordpress e estou fazendo uma nova com HTML/CSS e PHP.
Dentro da pasta dessa aplicação feita em wordpress, tem um arquivo chamado htaccesss, e tem a seguinte regra:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

Meu servidor está com as seguintes pastas:
[image: Apaguei o nome dos arquivos por uma questão de segurança]

Dentro da pasta 'main' existe todo um projeto web feito com php, e gostaria de que quando o usuário acessasse meu site, iria direto para a index.php da pasta main. Atualmente, quando acesso o site vai para a aplicação feita no wordpress.

Minha pergunta é: Como posso fazer o redirecionamento manual via htaccess para outra pasta?

-> Tentei utilizar essa regra: RedirectMatch ^/$ http://site.com.br/novapasta/

-> Tentei, também, essa regra: Redirect 301 /index.php    http://www.site.com.br.com/novapasta/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode criar um arquivo **.htaccess** dentro do seu **public_html** com o seguinte redirecionamento.

```
Redirect /index.html /main/
```

ou... Dependendo do seu projeto

```
Redirect /index.php /main/
```

Fonte: [DreamHost](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)